# Is there any way I can do type and field name checking with javascript json data received on my client

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following class on my server:

```
public class JsonDialog
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Errors { set; get; }
    public string Modified { set; get; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string PartitionKey { set; get; }
    public string PartitionKeyNew { set; get; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKeyNew { get; set; }
    public bool Success { set; get; }
}
```

In my MVC action method I return a JsonResult:

```
                return Json(new JsonDialog
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Errors = errors
                });
```

In my client code I have the following:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $form.serializeArray()
        })
        .done(onDone)
        .fail(onFail);


var onDone = function (json, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    json = json || {};
    if (json.Success) {
```

Because I am using a class on the server the compiler checks to ensure I don't make any spelling mistakes and for example it will not allow me to enter "success = false".  However on the client there's no checking and I could code json.sUccEss and it would still be okay with that but it would not give me the desired result.

Is there any way in Javascript that I can have some error checking like I have on the server? Anything like getting data into a class and having the IDE check that class fields are correct?

Comment: Depending on your IDE, you might be able to use [JSDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSDoc) or [Google Closure type annotations](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler). But that support is still much more limited than what a statically typed language like C# offers.

Comment: How could JSLint tell me if I spelled a variable that's coming across from the server differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this (partially) by creating a matching object in JS with, what I refer to as a 'factory' method (but that's a misnomer if you're using the term 'factory' as is referred to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx). It's really more analogous to 'casting', but since JS doesn't have strong typing, that's not exactly right either.

Obviously, this code pattern is also pretty verbose if all you're doing is trying to get intellisense working, but if you have methods on your JS-side object... we'll fictionally say: `JsonResult.prototype.markErrorsReviewed`...then this pattern where you get an instance of a given 'class' is helpful.

For the sake of brevity, I'm going to just use your C# class on which to base my JS:

```
var JsonResult = function () {
    this.Errors = [];
    this.Modified = null;
    this.ModifiedBy = null;
    //...rest of your properties, defaulted as necessary
}

JsonResult.factory = function (o) {
    var j = new JsonResult();
    $.extend(j, o);
    //do other processing here if needed (for example, ASP.NET serializes DateTime retardedly)
    return j;
}
```

**AJAX**:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(json, status, xhr) {
        var myobj = JsonResult.factory(json);
        //VS2010 will now give you intellisense w/ proper property names on myobj
        //Note: it's still buggy and sometimes won't detect things properly, but it usually works
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are good Text Editors that would help you, but there is no such thing for Javascript.

Editors like TextSublime can fake the code introspection and give an in file search to give help typing the same names.

IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans do a better job but are still really far away from what you want.
Javascript is not a language strongly typed like Java or C# (if we can say that they are...) so you won't find all those candy features you have with VS and C#.

This is what [NetBeans does](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/javascript-editor.html#basic) and this is not as advanced as you wish.

Comment: I'm using VS2010 and I don't think there's anything in the editor that stops me from typing anything after the word json :-(  I was hoping that there was some way to code in a class into javascript.

Comment: JavaScript is not a ctrl + space language sorry. You won't find anything like you have for C# or Java. Javascript is not a strongly language. It is way to permissive to enable such advanced code introspection features.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer doesn't make much sense to a native English speaker.

Comment: @Blazemonger This why is great website has an edit button bottom left corner. Maybe not native English speaker ready.

Answer (score 0):

May be there could be tools but if you can achieve that following ways:

In the controller you render the partially view instead of json result and pass the class object on that then on that view you have to write the objcetName.PropertyName and it would you check it.